# Setting %s in language not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I submit my form I have set flash data, with a line from my language file. But I need to include the `Uri` segment which is the `id` in with it so it would **out put** like so `Success: You have modified store id 20 settings!`

Currently it shows id but in wrong place: `Success: You have modified store id %s settings! 280`

**Language:**

`$lang['text_success'] = 'Success: You have modified store id %s settings!';`

**Set Flash Data**

```
sprintf($this->session->set_flashdata('success', $this->lang->line('text_success') . $this->uri->segment(5)));
```

How can I make it so where the %s in language line the id will show when message is outputted?

Answer (score 0):

Use this
I assume $this->uri->segment(5) is your id

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', sprintf($this->lang->line('text_success'), $this->uri->segment(5)));
```

Comment: Tried that did not work but found solution `$message = sprintf($this->lang->line('text_success'), $this->uri->segment(5));
   $this->session->set_flashdata('success', $message);`

Comment: I did the same as your solution

Answer (score 0):

I had another think about it and came up with this code here which works fine. I had to make another line with a variable and the place the variable in the set flash data.

```
$message = sprintf($this->lang->line('text_success'), $this->uri->segment(5));
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', $message);
```

**Correct message out put now:** `Success: You have modified store id 280 settings!`

**And on language file:**

```
$lang['text_success'] = 'Success: You have modified store id %s settings!';
```